# SAP/VBA "Run Time Error Method 'Text' of object 'ISAPTextFieldTarget' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, sap-gui

I have an error

> Run-Time error '-2147417856 (80010100)': Method 'Text' of object 'ISAPTextFieldTarget' failed

on below line which I have totally no clue why the error happened. The problem is, sometimes this error appears and sometimes not.

`cell2` is where the value of the cell for example :

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMF05A:0731/txtRF05A-SEL01[0,0]").Text = cell2
```

since the full code is very long, I will include part of it that triggered the error.

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text = "Check - document date is in the future" Then
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'First cell you want to copy to SAP. You can use Range("D6") if that will always be the first cell:
Set rFirst = Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row)

'Last cell you want to copy to SAP  'This code will go to the last cell in column D:
Set rLast = Range("H" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)   

'All the cells between the first and last cell. This is now a range you can loop through.
Set rSource = Range(rFirst, rLast)    

For Each cell2 In rSource

    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub:SAPMF05A:0731/txtRF05A-SEL01[0,0]").Text = cell2

    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

    'Run FB03 in new sap screen, number 2 or any active 2nd screen

    If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text = "No appropriate line item is contained in this document" Then

    'continue next code
```

I provide the picture of the error as per below.
The thing is if i click debug, and click resume. It will continue to proceed like nothing is error.

Comment: Is `cell2` text or numeric?  Not sure if it makes a difference, but could be it.  Try `CSTR(cell2)`.  Those first lines of your code block look a bit odd - you check the value of _wnd[0]/sbar_ and hit enter if it's a certain value, and then you hit enter anyway so surely no need for the `If...End If` block?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It is numeric, the value always in number. Also this is only the part of the code, there are more code above If...End If

Comment: SAP might need it as a string though - checking VBA code on one of my own reports I have `.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "300"` which is passing the numeric as a string which is why I suggest `CSTR`.

Comment: Maybe this link will help:  [Method 'Text' of object 'ISapTextFieldTarget' failed](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11552037/method-%27text%27-of-object-%27isaptextfieldtarget%27-fail.html).

Comment: According to the link you provided, the problem happened is where the code has CSTR, so I’m not really sure if i’m looking at different statement.

Comment: One possible mistake I see is that you use `cell2` which has the datatype `range`. That means that an `enter`might also be transmitted to the SAP session. I'd recommend to use `cell2.value2` or possibly better `cell2.text` explicitly.